# Unexpected "\n" with echo in php and html page

Tags: php, html

im having a problem with php and html.

inside a foreach im putting some html, a part of that is:

```
<img src="img/reboot.png" width="20px" height="20px" title="Reiniciar instancia <?php echo ($aInstancias_oci[0]);?>" onclick="reboot_instance ('<?php echo ($aInstancias_oci[1]);?>', '<?php echo ($aInstancias_oci[0]);?>','<?php  echo ($aInstancias_oci[3]);?>')" />
```

which should give something like this:

```
<img src="img/reboot.png" width="20px" height="20px" title="Reiniciar instancia $instance_name" onclick="reboot_instance ('ocid', 'instance_name','VM')" />
```

but its inserting an enter after the M on VM, only in the last element of the foreach, like this:

```
<img src="img/reboot.png" width="20px" height="20px" title="Reiniciar instancia $instance_name" onclick="reboot_instance ('ocid', 'instance_name','VM
')" />
```

so the onclick on the last element aint works.

the rest work just fine.

Anyone knows what could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your last variable contains a line break. You can try removing it from source or at display.

Comment: Try it with trim(). Instead of _echo ($aInstancias_oci[3]);_ try _echo trim($aInstancias_oci[3]);_ (Note that echo does not need parentheses, so I removed them).